# Import "phonenumber_field.modelfields" could not be resolved

Tags: python, django, import

I have django project and I try to add phonenumber package,
I've done 'pip install django-phonenumber-field[phonenumbers]'
and I imported the library to my .models
but it shows up as an error but it works anyways, the error is called: "Import "phonenumber_field.modelfields" could not be resolved(reportMissingImports)"
how do I fix the problem so it won't tell me its a problem and will work like everything else?

Please help :3
[my code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW3V3.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding it to settings as well. Here’s the example from the [docs](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field#basic-usage):

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'phonenumber_field',
    ...
]
```

Comment: I've done it and still shows an error

Answer (score 0):

Don’t do that `pip install django-phonenumber-field[phonenumbers]` and try this instead `pip install django-phonenumber-field`

Answer (score -2):

I'm having this same issue. I've tried a few different things, including installing an older version of django-phonenumber-field, and verifying that the install location is included in the PATH variable. Ultimately I set `#type: ignore` after the import to get Pylance to shut up about it, but would love if someone had a better solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33409055)